# Getting other Java project JARs into Docker image?

Tags: java, docker, maven, quarkus

I have a Quarkus project that uses some other common code from another Java project that I use `mvn install` on so it has access to it locally. Within Quarkus applications  theres a `Dockerfile.jvm` that you can use to build the Docker image. The question is how do I get this other project into the Quarkus application's Docker image that I want to use? If I use `mvn package` and copy the JAR files into the `target/` folder it doesn't seem to get picked up so I'm not sure what other ways to try this. Do I need to maybe copy the JARs into the `target/` folder and then run use a `mvn install` from that path or something?

Comment: If the Quarkus project uses the other, it should be in Maven `<dependencies>` and, if so, the Quarkus build should automatically include it. Am I missing something? Can you provide any more details about your problem or a way to reproduce it?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos hello. This is the included dependency inside my application's pom.xml `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>`. If I try to run `./mvnw quarkus:dev` it will give something similar to `Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.stuff:class-name:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example.stuff:common:jar:1.` To resolve this locally I run `mvn install` but I'm not sure how to resolve this in Docker.

Comment: Oh actually it looks like if I have the other common code library that my application is using as a dependency and it's installed locally using `mvn install` when I run `mvn package` on my Quarkus application it seems to be able to package actual dependencies with it so that I can build the Docker image. This seems fine locally but how would I do this within a CI/CD pipeline like Tekton? I'm assuming we would have to clone both of these applications at the same stage and run `mvn install` there before we package our Quarkus application.

Comment: Yes, right. So in the CI/CD you have to: either build the dependency before the main project always, or make sure the dependency is built and installed in the CI/CD system's local repository; even better if you can deploy it in a Maven repository like Nexus, either private or public.